# Script running another script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

i have a #!/bin/sh script that ask the user questions for example enter your age.
I need another #!/bin/sh script that start the first script and send static answers to it.
How can I send answers from one script to another script and answers it questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Calling a sh scipt in another is just like calling a script from the prompt...maybe i am missing something or you have to improve your question/needs...

Comment: you need expect , it will feed in to your script depending of input from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script you want to test reads standard input, then use that.

```
for input in 1 2 17 42 63 -1 0 1234568890; do
    echo "$input" | ./otherscript
done
```

Or if your `otherscript` already runs an input loop (say, with an empty input as the exit condition), feed it a here document:

```
./otherscript <<HERE
1
2
17
42
63
-1
0
1234567890

HERE
```

If you need to input multiple values for each run, you can combine the two;

```
while read age name color; do
    (echo "$age"; echo "$name"; echo "$color") | ./otherscript
done <<HERE
1 Baby white
2 Sister yellow
17 Teen black
42 Dad mauve
63 Grandpa chartreuse
0 Piglet pink
-1 Prince purple
1234567890 Ghod rainbowey
HERE
```

Unix tools are regularly designed to read parameters from the command line instead, though. This is one of the many reasons that is a better design.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the script that asks for inputs, userage.sh and the calling script caller.sh

If you want userage.sh to take input without user prompts, redo it so that if there are no arguments, take user inputs and if there are arguments, take those arguments as inputs.